# Error in RED5 Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Failed

Tags: red5

I got **Red5** test page but while opening **Installer** I am getting **error** and I am also opened ports `5080,1935,5229` and `843` .The error like below I am getting.

```
Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Failed
Trying to connect to war location
```

In log getting these Errors

```
     WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Exception creating connection
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@1a44651[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]] did not accept task: org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection$WaitForHandshakeTask@1345e03
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.execute(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:226) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection.startWaitForHandshake(RTMPConnection.java:423) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:176) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:56) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.createRTMPMinaConnection(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:297) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.sessionCreated(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:61) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:772) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:459) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$700(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:913) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionCreated(IoFilterAdapter.java:74) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:459) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:452) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoServiceListenerSupport.fireSessionCreated(IoServiceListenerSupport.java:211) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:542) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:510) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1120) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@12e54e rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@1a44651[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:622) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.execute(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:223) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
2016-02-11 15:06:20,728 [NioProcessor-4] INFO  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection - Rejected message: Packet [[header data type=20, channel=3, timer=0], [message timestamp=0]] on AJBBLZP7WF0FT
2016-02-11 15:06:30,651 [NioProcessor-5] WARN  o.r.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager - Exception creating connection
org.springframework.core.task.TaskRejectedException: Executor [java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@1a44651[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]] did not accept task: org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection$WaitForHandshakeTask@171285a
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.execute(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:226) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnection.startWaitForHandshake(RTMPConnection.java:423) ~[red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:176) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPConnManager.createConnection(RTMPConnManager.java:56) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.createRTMPMinaConnection(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:297) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaIoHandler.sessionCreated(RTMPMinaIoHandler.java:61) [red5-server-common-1.0.6-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.6-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$TailFilter.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:772) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:459) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.access$700(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:48) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain$EntryImpl$1.sessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:913) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.IoFilterAdapter.sessionCreated(IoFilterAdapter.java:74) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.callNextSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:459) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.filterchain.DefaultIoFilterChain.fireSessionCreated(DefaultIoFilterChain.java:452) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.service.IoServiceListenerSupport.fireSessionCreated(IoServiceListenerSupport.java:211) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.addNow(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:542) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.handleNewSessions(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:510) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor.access$400(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:68) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoProcessor$Processor.run(AbstractPollingIoProcessor.java:1120) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64) [mina-core-2.0.10-SNAPSHOT.jar:na]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask@7794fd rejected from java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@1a44651[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823) [na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:326) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.schedule(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:533) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:622) ~[na:1.8.0_20]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.execute(ThreadPoolTaskScheduler.java:223) ~[spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar:4.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

Please can anyone help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of Searching I m solved my issue by adding my IP Address to the WebApps/Installer/WEB-INF/red5_web properties file like below

```
webapp.virtualHosts=localhost, localhost:5080, my ip address
```

now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the 1.0.6-RELEASE instead of 1.0.6-SNAPSHOT. Also the installer needs some work since googlecode (where the wars are hosted) is pretty much done.

Comment: Can you tell me step by step process what i want to do in 1.0.6 -RELEASE.Please I am very new to RED 5

Comment: There is some up-to-date info on the main wiki, start there; if you use linux, try this https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/wiki/Installation-on-Linux

Comment: I m using windows 8. Now demos are installed but while running demos from webapps/root/Demos  It showing alert as Please check URI String Connection and try again

Comment: Can you help me about this

Comment: Is your red5 instance running? did you connect with port 5080? Try http://localhost:5080/demos from your browser on the server itself.

Comment: Ya.I m connected  with port 5080 but demos are not working

Comment: The original error shows that requests are hitting the server from RTMP, which would be port 1935 (which is default and correct). Which demo is not working?

Comment: The Server side demos are working i.e. http://myip:5080/demos/ these demos working perfectly but demos and installer inside red5/webapps/root/demos are not working. Please  help me regarding this

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir.That is Adobe flash player problem.I changed in Global Security Setting Manager.It is working now

Comment: once again thank you for spending your valuable time